# Saving mail into Sent items in JavaMail

Tags: email, jakarta-mail, attachment

I am using something like the following to save a copy of the sent message in the user Sent folder in JavaMail. It works fine for emails with no attachment and for emails whose attachments are less than 1MB. But program stops before the code is actually executed for attachments greater than 1MB. Any idea how to deal with this one?

```
    String host = ReadConfigPropertiesFile.getPropertyValue("server.host");
        String smtpHost = ReadConfigPropertiesFile.getPropertyValue("smtp.host");
        String from = "test@myserver.net";
        String to = "test@myserver.net";
// Get system properties
        Properties properties = System.getProperties();
// Setup smtp mail server
        properties.setProperty(smtpHost, host);
        properties.setProperty("mail.mime.encodeparameters", "true");
        //  properties.setProperty("mail.mime.decodeparameters","true");
        properties.setProperty("mail.mime.encodefilename", "true");
        // properties.setProperty("mail.mime.decodefilename","true");
// Get the default Session object.
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);
// Define message
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
        message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                new InternetAddress(to));

        message.setSubject("Peace ", "UTF-8");
// Create the message part
        BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

// Fill the message body
        messageBodyPart.setContent("Hello attachment", "text/html; charset=UTF-8");

        Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
        multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

        String[] filename = {"C:/Users/Dake/Desktop/music.mp3"};
        for (int i = 0; i < filename.length; i++) {
            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename[i]);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            // messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename[i]);
            //messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8; name="+MimeUtility.encodeText(filename[i]));
            // messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", filename[i]);
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(filename[i], "UTF-8", null)); //encode filename
            //bodyPart.setFileName(MimeUtility.encodeText(attachment.getName(), "UTF-8", null));
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
        }
        // Put parts in message
        message.setContent(multipart);
        //set the time
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:MM:SS");
        Date date = new Date();
        String sentDate = df.format(date);
        Date dd = (Date) df.parse(sentDate);
        message.setSentDate(date);

        // Send the message
        Transport.send(message);
        System.out.println("Message sent...");
        // Copy message to "Sent Items" folder as read
        Store store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect(host, "user", "userpwd");

        Folder folder = (Folder) store.getFolder("Sent");
        if (!folder.exists()) {
            folder.create(Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES);
        }
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        System.out.println("appending...");
        // folder.appendMessages(new Message[]{message});
        try {

            folder.appendMessages(new Message[]{message});
           // Message[] msgs = folder.getMessages();
            message.setFlag(FLAGS.Flag.RECENT, true);

        } catch (Exception ignore) {
            System.out.println("error processing message " + ignore.getMessage());
        } finally {
            store.close();
           // folder.close(false);
        }

        System.out.println("Msg send and saved ....");
    }
```

When I run the above code, it displays the *appending....* and it stops there forever. And I am using Apache James server 3.0-beta4 as the mail server.

Comment: I've added your code inside my Apache James server (version 3.0-beta1) and everything is working fine. Maybe you just forgot to close the SMTPTransport connection before starting to save the message in the Sent folder?

Comment: When you get an exception, print the exception, or the stack trace. Not some uninformative message of your own devising.

Answer (score 0):

Is your server breaking the connection because it's taking too long to send the message to be appended?  (If so, how long is it taking?)

Or is the server breaking the connection because it won't allow you to append a message that large?

Do you get any useful information from the server in the [debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug)?

Comment: Hi Bill, I have edited my question and check it again. With regard to the server debug output, I can smoothly connect to the SMTP, IMAP and POP3 servers using telnet.

Comment: telnet only tells you that you can connect.  I want to see the debug output so I can see what commands JavaMail is sending and what responses the server is returning.  But it sounds like your application is hanging when trying to append the message.  The debug output will help us see what's happening when it hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a old question, but maybe this helps you or some others.
I guess the problem of your code is that you try to manipulate the Recent-Flag: `message.setFlag(FLAGS.Flag.RECENT, true);`. According to the [IMAP-Standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-11) the Recent-Flag can't be altered by clients.